# How to cache pages until modified something

Tags: express, caching, nginx, varnish

I need to know if there is any way using Node.js (Express), Varnish, Nginx to cache pages until the user modified something...

My users creates pages with content, like a blog, and I want cache all pages that are not modified, but if the user enter new content again in the page and change something, refresh the cache... What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A common technique for static files is to put a hash of the file in the filename. Then as you make content changes, your CDN/webserver cache recognises this as a new file because the URI has changed.

For dynamic content, **nginx** has a *proxy_cache_key* directive. So you can define what should constitute a cache hit or miss, eg:

```
proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
```

Using the cookie allows you to cache dynamic pages without serving content that was generated for a different user. Or as described in the [directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key), you could cache based on url arguments:

```
proxy_cache_key "$uri$is_args$args";
```

You will need to understand how your application works and set the key appropriately.

Comment: But how can I apply that to dynamics url? Like this: www.mydomain.com/{idpost}/seo-name thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks... imaging the user make a blog post, I cached until the user modified it... I have stored the date modified of the post, but... my real question is, how can I decide if I need to go to the database again or get from cache. Thanks again!!